# JKS instance in java able to load pkcs12 keystore

Tags: java, security, ssl, keystore

Good day everyone. I have a code in my application as given where I am generating private key and cerificate as below.

```
 ClassPathResource storeFile = new ClassPathResource(SAML_KEYSTORE_PATH);
      KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
      keystore.load(storeFile.getInputStream(), SAML_KEYSTORE_PASS.toCharArray());
      PrivateKey spPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(SAML_PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS,
          SAML_PRIVATE_KEY_PASS.toCharArray());
      X509Certificate spPublicCert =
          (X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificate(SAML_PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS);
```

SAML_KEYSTORE_PATH has the path to /saml/samlKeystore.jks file which is not JKS it is generated using the -storetype PKCS12 using keytool. It is just the extension is .jks format. I am not sure how this is working, why I am able to generate those key and cerificate from pkcs12 keystore format and using jks instance in java/kotlin. Can someone please shed some light how this is working ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: *Why* is the extension .jks? Are you sure it is in PCKS#12 format? and hasn't been converted? Can you view it with `keytool -list -storetype PKCS12`?

Comment: yes I did not code it but I did check the Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN...The format is just given .jks while createing it using the keytool

Comment: The extension (and filename) doesn't matter at all. If the _contents_ is indeed PKCS12, and you request `KeyStore.getInstance("jks")` on Java 8u60 up by default it is capable of reading PKCS12 as well; see [the release notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u60-relnotes.html) at "Keystore Compatibility Mode".

Comment: Yes it in PKCS12 format. I am convinced with the above comment. Thanks guys.